# Custom Annotation JPSThumbnailAnnotation getting stretched while taking screenshot of MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am using [JPSThumbnailAnnotation](https://github.com/jpsim/JPSThumbnailAnnotation) to show Annotation with image on MKMapView. Everything works well and map shows annotation with image which looks like image attached below[image]

Here i need to take screenshot of MapView and upload that image to facebook, following is the code which is used to take screenshot of view

```
/* Get the entire on screen map as Image */
CGSize size = self.mapView.bounds.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[self.mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Problem is.. in screenshot [JPSThumbnailAnnotation](https://github.com/jpsim/JPSThumbnailAnnotation) getting stretched which is looks like following image [image]

So unable to find the reason why this annotations getting stretched in screenshot only.

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.